# How to deploy .net core windows service using Azure devops CI/CD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running into an azure specific problem. So I have a windows service that I have created. I need to configure my azure pipeline to deploy it as well whenever rest of the project is built and deployed.

Not sure how to go about it because I don't see any .net core specific pipeline task in azure.

I am not sure how exactly to deploy the project that I have. I am stuck after downloading the artifact which contains all the dlls that have been compiled by Azure devops build.

Comment: Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) which could help you .

Comment: @aakmu did you manage to find any way to deploy .net core windows service to azure devops? 
I am facing an issue with CD pipeline.